# EJB Timer Wildly Wrong

Tags: windows, jakarta-ee, timer, glassfish, ejb

I am using an EJB timer with Glassfish.  The code works fine in many installations, but on one, the timed results are very much off.  The timer is created like this:

```
TimerService ts = sc.getTimerService();
Timer timer = ts.createTimer(20000, "myTimer");
```

This works correctly on many systems.  But we have one single Windows installation (a specific computer) however where the timer does not fire for 5, 6, 7 even as long as ten minutes.  The times vary quite a bit.  The computer is not busy as far as we can tell, it show single digit CPU usage percentages at all times.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: Does not help that the timer uses the underlying os for scheduling? But I have not seen delay in minutes. Are you sure that the timer is getting invoked? May be its failing some post condition. Having said that, I will profile the jvm for thread locking issue or garbage collection classes (but garbage collection causing delay in minutes is insane, so must be a thread issue)

Comment: We are certain the code is generally functional,  the timer is created, but does not expire until very late.  We have new information though.  Sometimes the delay timeout is exactly 10 minutes, to the ms.  This turns out to be related to the pool-idle-timeout-in-seconds on the EJB pool.  Reducing pool-idle-timeout-in-seconds causes the maximum delay to change.  I conclude that an EJB is preventing the timer from expiring until that blocking EJB is garbage collected for being idle.  Again, this only happens on one of several production servers we have, all identical (we think).

Comment: I am still wondering if others have seen this.  We now have multiple computers (Windows) that show this problem.  On a system that was completely idle for a few weeks, with a single-use EJB timer created every 25 seconds, the system went though a bad time when the timer expired only after a 2 or 3 *days*.